# Low-pass filter - choosing R values dependent on the load impedance

Tags: filter, impedance, proteus, passive-filter

I need to design a low-pass RC filter that is connected to an oscilloscope at the output. The oscilloscope has a load impedance of 1MΩ||20pF. I have to choose values for R and C, taking this load impedance into account.

Originally I chose R = 1kΩ based off another post here (which I can't find now). Then, using the formula:$$\text{f}_c =\frac{\text{1}}{\text{2}\pi\text{RC}}$$ for my desired cutoff frequency of 10kHz, this gave me C = 15.9nF

Then I found [this](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/CRtool.php) website which calculates the RC values for you if you enter the desired cutoff. It gave me R=160Ω and C=0.1uF

So here's the problem: using my values gives a real cutoff of 10,010Hz, and using the website's values gives 9947Hz. Clearly my values get closer to the chosen cutoff, but I haven't taken the load impedance into account because I don't know how it would affect the values. In a simulator, both circuits behave almost exactly the same, but I'm concerned that the simulator's oscilloscope doesn't have a 1MΩ impedance.

Can somebody explain how the load impedance would affect the choice of values, and which values I should choose? My set, the website's set, or a completely different set?

The circuits and their frequency responses are below, so you can see how they're basically the same.

[image]

Comment: The site you linked to makes its suggestion based on available parts.  Yours is mathematically correct, but you will not be able to build it as calculated - you cannot buy a 15.9 nF capacitor.

Comment: Given the relatively flat "cutoff" of a simple RC filter, it doesn't matter that much if the cutoff is exactly where you want it.

Comment: @JRE thanks, that makes sense about the available parts and actually helps with another part of this. Are you able to help with the load impedance part of my question? I'm not sure whether the 1MΩ load actually affects the values or not if we're talking real-world building and not the simulator. The question I'm doing asks me to take the load impedance into account when choosing R and C, but I don't know how.

Comment: @JRE I've seen on another post that "a large R and a small C will load down the source less but can't drive much of anything at the other end", so does this mean that a 1kΩ resistor and 15.9nF capacitor wouldn't work with the 1MΩ oscilloscope? Would the 160Ω/0.1uF combo be better as the values are closer together?

Comment: The problem is the large R.  Imagine you use 1M as the R in your filter.  The R and the input impedance form a voltage divider to reduce the signal in general.  With a large R you also use a small C.  The C for the filter becomes so small that the capacitance of the scope input is as large as the filter C, which will change the cutoff.

Comment: @JRE so in that case, using the 160Ω/0.1uF combo would be the best choice right? It uses available parts and 0.1uF (100,000pF), is much higher than the scope capacitance of 20pF, so the cutoff should remain the same?

Comment: Exactly.  I just don't know of a way or rule to figure the parts.

Answer (score 2):

Well, we have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXTGtZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The transfer function is given by:

$$\underline{\mathcal{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)=\frac{\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\text{||}\text{R}_\text{L}\text{||}\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_\text{L}}}{\text{R}+\left(\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\text{||}\text{R}_\text{L}\text{||}\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_\text{L}}\right)}\tag1$$

Now, we find that:

$$\left|\underline{\mathcal{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{\text{R}_\text{L}}{\sqrt{\left(\text{R}+\text{R}_\text{L}\right)^2+\left(\omega\text{RR}_\text{L}\left(\text{C}+\text{C}_\text{L}\right)\right)^2}}\tag2$$

When \$\omega\to0\$ we get:

$$\lim_{\omega\to0}\left|\underline{\mathcal{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{\text{R}_\text{L}}{\text{R}+\text{R}_\text{L}}\tag3$$

Now, we need to solve (in order to find the cutoff frequency):

$$\left|\underline{\mathcal{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{\text{R}_\text{L}}{\text{R}+\text{R}_\text{L}}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\omega=\frac{1}{\text{R}_\text{L}}\cdot\frac{\text{R}+\text{R}_\text{L}}{\text{CR}+\text{R}\text{C}_\text{L}}\tag4$$

Using your values we need to have:

$$2\pi\cdot10000=\frac{1}{10^6}\cdot\frac{\text{R}+10^6}{\text{R}\cdot\text{C}+\text{R}\cdot20\cdot10^{-12}}\tag5$$

Choosing a value of \$\text{R}=1\space\text{k}\Omega\$ we find for \$\text{C}\$:

$$\text{C}=\frac{5005 - 2 \pi}{100000000000\pi}\approx15.9114\space\text{nF}\tag6$$